# include metadata in stripe checkout session

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, metadata

I am using the pre-built stripe checkout session in node.js. here's my function:

```
app.get('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
    let customer = {
        price: req.query.price,
        quantity: req.query.quantity,
        page: req.query.page,
        email: req.query.email,
        name: req.query.name
    }

    // insertIntoDbPreCheckout(customer, req, res)

    let successurl = 'http://localhost:1111/' + customer.page + ''
    let failedurl = 'http://localhost:1111/' + customer.page + ''
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    metadata: {
      'description': customer.page
    },
    customer_email: customer.email,
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'cad',
          product_data: {
            name: customer.page,
          },
          unit_amount: customer.price,
        },
        quantity: customer.quantity,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: successurl,
    cancel_url: failedurl,
  })

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});
```

i am trying to pass `METADATA` through, but it isn't letting me.

I cannot find anything online that shows me how to do this, and it is not working no matter what I try. How can i fix this?

edit:

when i log the customers, it shows like this:

```
     email: 'uuu@u.com',
  invoice_prefix: '9FC11B6D',
  invoice_settings: { custom_fields: null, default_payment_method: null, footer: null },
  livemode: false,
  metadata: {},
```

as you can see, `metadata` is empty

Comment: What do you mean it's not letting you? Your request looks valid, I would expect that `metadata` to end up on the Checkout session. Are you encountering an API error? What does the error say?

Comment: @NolanH just edited my q

Answer (score 1):

Based on the updated question, this is expected. The `metadata` you've provided is on the Checkout session itself. You're examining the Customer object created by the Checkout session, which does not have `metadata` (yet).

You can add customer metadata if you want to, by [updating](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update?lang=node) the customer:

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.update(
  'cus_123',
  {metadata: {order_id: '6735'}}
);
```

Existing metadata would be on the Checkout session [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object?lang=node#checkout_session_object-metadata).

Comment: ohhh i see okay. yes this makes sense, so the metadata is being passed through, just not through the customer, but through the session. So is it possible then to create a checkout session for a specific customer. so i would create a customer and then instatntly create a checkout session for them? Like how would i specifiy a checkout session for a specific customer?

Comment: Yes, you can do this by creating the customer first (optionally with metadata!), then using that customer with the Checkout session `customer` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should include metadata in stripe.checkout.sessions.create as

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  line_items: [
    {
      name: 'name',
      amount: 10 * 100,
      currency: 'usd',
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
  payment_intent_data: {
        metadata: {
          userId: req.user.userId,
          nftId: body.nftId,
          price: body.price,
          email: req.user.email,
          ownerId: body.ownerId,
        },
      },
      client_reference_id: req.user.email,
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: 'success_url',
      cancel_url: 'cancel_url',
    });
```

in webhook you can get the meta data as **req.body.data.object.metadata**

Comment: Nice yeah the formatting cuts off in the answer but this is right it has to be under the key of payment_intent_data -> "payment_intent_data": {metadata: { key:value}}